# Implement Mouse Click in Repast Simphony(Java)

Tags: repast-simphony

I want to implement the a model including a functionality that allows me to do various things by clicking the mouse on its interface. However I am not able to find any out if mouse click is possible to be implemented on the Repast Simphony based Model. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse click can be implemented in Repast. Just go to Import projects -> Other-> Import Repast Example Models-> Mousetrap.

This model allows the user to use mouse left/right click as well as Scroll. The classes in the model would be helpful :)